# In Asp.net MVC 4 multiple inline row update in single click using WebGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I wants to do multiple inline rows update when click on Update button outside the Grid.
Below is the url of sample project I am referring.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/create-an-editable-webgrid-in-mvc4-to-implement-crud-operati/

But in this sample the admin is updating each row by row. But I want all rows to be updated using update button outside the grid, so that users of my application can click on that update button after they complete editing of the entire grid.

Please help me if anyone knows how to achieve this. Also let me know if you wants any more information. The details of the application and the source code you can get from the above link.

Note :- I am using here WebGrid in ASP.MVC 4, if you know any other free grid that can be used in this scenario, please let me know.

Thanks a lot